# How to copy multiple files with varying version numbers from one directory to another using bash?

Tags: linux, bash, copy

I have a folder ***/home/user/Document/filepath*** where I have three files namely file1-1.1.0.txt, file2-1.1.1.txt, file3-1.1.2.txt

and another folder named ***/home/user/Document/backuppath*** where I have to move files from ***/home/user/Document/folderpath*** which has file1-1.0.0.txt, file2-1.0.1.txt and file3-1.0.2.txt

1. task is to copy the specific files from folder path to backup path.

To summarize:

```
the below is the files.txt where I listed the files which has to be copied:

file1-*.txt
file2-*.txt
```

```
The below is the move.sh script that execute the movements
for file in `cat files.txt`; do cp "/home/user/Document/folderpath/$file" "/home/user/Documents/backuppath/" ; done
```

for the above script I am getting the error like

```
cp: cannot stat '/home/user/Document/folderpath/file1-*.txt': No such file or directory found
cp: cannot stat '/home/user/Document/folderpath/file2-*.txt': No such file or directory found
```

what I would like to accomplish is that I would like to use the script to copy specific files using * in the place of version numbers., since the version number may vary in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You have wildcard characters in your files.txt. In your `cp` command, you are using quotes. These quotes prevent the wildcards to be expanded, as you can clearly see from the error message.

One obvious possibility is to not use quotes:

```
 cp /home/user/Document/folderpath/$file /home/user/Documents/backuppath/
```

Or not use a loop at all:

```
 cp $(<files.txt) /home/user/Documents/backuppath/
```

However, this would of course break if one line in your `files.txt` is a filename pattern which contains white spaces. Therefore, I would recommend a second loop over the expanded pattern:

```
while read file # Puts the next line into 'file'
do
  for f in $file # This expands the pattern in 'file'
  do
     cp "/home/user/Document/folderpath/$f" /home/user/Documents/backuppath
  done
done < files.txt
```